# How to hang curves between two points using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a procedural power line generator with Geometry Nodes.

I have a single pole which I instance across a plane. The pole object has separate materials on the faces where wires are allowed to start and end.

I then instance curves on all the green faces. I use geometry proximity to snap the other ends to the red faces.

The problem is that they connect in straight lines. I'd like to have them hang realistically between the poles.

I've tried a lot of crazy stuff with the curve handles, but that doesn't seem to work:

[image: Power line mess]

My reference/inspiration is @sozap's great power line generator in this [thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/buildings-and-streets-with-some-geometry-nodes/1364541/5) on [Blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org).

Here's the pole:

[image: Simple pole mesh]

And the node tree in 3 parts:

[image: p1]

[image: p2]

[image: p3]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I would look for the yt channel of Johnny matthews. He is one of the developers of GN. He explains exactly that in a good tutorial.

Comment: Thanks @Chris! That solved the problem.

Comment: you are welcome ‼️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Set the Handle Type to Vector and then use two Set Handle Position nodes to adjust the Z positions of the handles.

[image: Powerlines in Blender]